# free subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

In the example section of the wikipedia article on the [the Ping Pong lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma), you can see how to construct a free subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with two generators 
$$ a_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, 
\ \ \ \ \ a_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is it possible to construct free subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with an arbitrary number of generators in a similar way (using the Ping Pong lemma)? Do such subgroups even exist?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a noob at group theory.

Comment: Dear Herbert: such subgroups definitely exist (if by "arbitrary number" you mean "arbitrary finite number"). Indeed, the free group on two elements contains a copy of the free group on $n$ elements, for any positive integer $n$. As for whether such a subgroup can be explicitly constructed with the Ping Pong lemma, I am not sure, but I would venture that it probably can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subgroups of free groups are free (this is well-known theorem by Nilsen-Schreier). Free group $H$ on two generators $F_2$ contains a subgroup of countable rank (for example, its commutator subgroup). This implies that $F_2$ contains any subgroup of finite rank. Indeed, if $H=\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\rangle$, then $\langle a_1,\dots, a_n\rangle$ gives you a free subgroup in $F_2$ of rank $n$.

So the free subgroup on $2$ generators that you've found in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ gives you automatically free subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ of arbitrary countable rank.

Comment: thank you! So, just to check: If I have a free group of rank 2 with generators $a$ and $b$, I could construct a subgroup of rank four by picking generators $ab, abb, abbb, abbbb$. By Nilsen-Schreier this is then the free group with four generators.

Comment: "...of arbitrary **countable** rank..."

Comment: You can even find free subgroups of uncountable rank.

Comment: @studiosus In $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, perhaps, but not in $F_2$.

Comment: @user1729: Of course in $SL(2,R)$, the question was about it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems worth noting that one can also explicitly construct free subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ of arbitrarily large (finite) rank.

Namely, if we let $\Gamma(N)$ denote the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ consisting of matrices that are $\equiv 1 \bmod N$, then for $N \geq 3$,
the group $\Gamma(N)$ is free, on a number of generators that grows something like $N^3$.

Comment: Where to find a proof of this fact, i.e., that $\Gamma(N)$ is free?

Comment: @Dolddrums: Dear Doldrums, It is a torsion free discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acting freely on the upper half-plane, and the quotient of the upper half-plane by this group is a punctured Riemann surface, whose $\pi_1$ is then free group. Covering space theory identifies this $\pi_1$ with $\Gamma(N)$.  This is fairly standard, but I'm not sure what the best reference is.  If you would like to find a good reference, one way might be to ask another question specifically seeking a reference for this fact.  Another would be to google "Congruence subgroups" and "free groups". ...

Comment: (The groups $\Gamma(N)$ are called *principal congruence subgroups*.)  Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was aware of principal congruence subgroups; but shamefully had not realized properties such as free-ness, nor had they been mentioned my textbooks on algebraic topology or on modular forms. The basic outline is now clear: Thinking of the quotient as a polygon with sides identified also with punctures, it deformation-retracts to a wedge of $n$-circles and so $\pi_1$ is a free group. But certain points still remain, like, a polygonal fundamental domain can always be found, or that the $\pi_1$ of the quotient is free. These are probably true and well-known, if a bit obscure.

Comment: @Doldrums: Dear Doldrums, If you know something about modular forms, then you probably know about the standard fundamental domain for $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$.  Now using coset reps. for $\Gamma(N)$ in this group, it is easy to make a polygonal fundamental domain for $\Gamma(N)$. Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt E: Thanks. That too is now very clear. Thanks again for all the detailed explanations.