# a potential application of the ping-pong lemma?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

From my understanding, a simple result of the ping-pong lemma would state that if we have a set of linear transformations (matrices) $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ all of the same dimension, then if $\mathrm{Im}(A_i) \cap \mathrm{Im}(A_j) = \{ 0 \}$, then any sequence of product of matrices among $A_i$ will uniquely identify the product.

Is that correct?

This is related to my question here:

[under what conditions a product of matrices is the identity matrix (more complicated than that)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823194/under-what-conditions-a-product-of-matrices-is-the-identity-matrix-more-complic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false even if $n=1$: Take a single matrix of finite order: $A$ such that $A^k=1$ for some $k>0$, or a single nilpotent matrix: $A$ such that $A^k=0$ for some $k> 0$. Then 
$$
A^k=A^{2k}.
$$
Thus, you cannot recover power $N$ of the matrix from the value $A^N$.

Here is what you need in order to play ping-point, where I assume that you are working with real $d\times d$ matrices:

a. Assume also that each $A_i$ is diagonalizable over the real numbers (with positive eigenvalues) and that for each matrix $A_i$ the multiplicity of the highest eigenvalue equals $1$.

b. For each $A_i$ define the subspace $B_i\subset R^d$ spanned by eigenvector corresponding to the highest eigenvalues, and the complementary subspace $C_i$ spanned by the rest of the eigenvectors. Then you require that for each $i$, the subspace $B_i$ is **not contained** in the union
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^n C_j.
$$

Now you can play ping-pong: there exists $N>0$ such that the matrices 
$$
A_1^N,...,A_n^N
$$
are free generators of a free semigroup in the (multiplicative) semigroup of $d\times d$ matrices.

One can get away with less than what I listed, but the above always works.

Comment: btw, @studiosus, it seems like the ping-pong metaphore here is important and actually means something (you used "play ping-pong"). why is it exactly called ping-pong?

Comment: mm, also you have the $N$ here. So does that mean that a product such as $A_1 A_2$ won't be necessarily uniquely identified if $N \ge 2$? What role does $N$ play here?

Comment: also, condition b sounds very strong and likely to never be satisfied. $B_i$ for each $i$ is just the span of a single vector, so you want that vector to not be in *any* of the other spaces. Isn't it likely that a single vector will be spanned by one of the $C_j$? (clearly not $C_i$)  For example, it limits $n$ to be smaller or equal to $d$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @polynomial: Yes, you are mistaken: A generic line is not contained in the union of a finite number of proper linear subspaces. (Draw 10000 lines in the plane and pick a point in the plane at random. What are the chances that this point lies in one of the lines?) As for N: It is needed as the original matrices might not generate a free semigroup.

Comment: As for the Ping pong metaphor: If you read the proof you might see why it is used, otherwise you can just ignore it.