# Finding a set of matrices that lets you read off order of multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

I am looking for a class of invertible matrices, $\{A_i\}$, where if I have a finite set of $n$ such matrices, $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ *that do not commute*, then if I multiply them in some order to get a resulting matrix $S$, by looking at $S$ I can quickly "read off" the order that the $A_1,...,A_n$ were multiplied in to obtain $S$.

I am wondering if there are any obvious candidates for such a collection of matrices?  My only idea is that the collection of matrices could be a collection of transposition matrices, so that when I give you the resulting permutation matrix obtained by multiplying the collection of transpositions in some way, then you can read off that ordering, but I am wondering if there is a better way, and especially a way where I can read off the ordering of the product "quickly".

Comment: Products of transpositions in the usual group of permutations of n symbols do not have unique factorization. Maybe some particular subset of them?

Comment: @coffeemath ya I see that now, perhaps if the transpositions do not commute?

Comment: Do you mean a set of transpositions say T so that f,g do not commute for *any* choice of f,g in T? [If so it seems T could not have many transpositions in it, I don't know what the largest size of T could be.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of matrices do you need? If you work over a field of characteristic zero (or anything that contains $\mathbb{Z}$), then you can choose a pair of matrices [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545584/free-subgroups-of-sl2-mathbbr). They generate a free subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ under multiplication, and hence a free subsemigroup if we are to prohibit inverting them. For larger matrix sizes pad the diagonal with ones.
Sorry for posting as a guest.
Edit: [proper reference](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sanov_subgroup_in_SL(2,Z)_is_free_of_rank_two) (the linked question seems to consider $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: ok but is it the case that given a product of this free subgroup, you can see what the elements are that gave that product and in what order?

Comment: Basically, given a product of such elements, say from this free group you mention, then I want to be able to get an algorithm I can use to quickly read off what the exact product was (I need to assume the product I am given is a single matrix, i.e. is not expanded out in some form)

Comment: Do you want an explicit algorithm or merely a theoretical result? The latter follows just from the definition of the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) on two generators: if we constructed two products of its elements, they are distinct as elements iff they are distinct as words. For the former... if the matrices are $A$ and $B$, then $AB^{-1}$ contains either a negative row or a negative column. So you can just multiply your product (e.g. from the right) by the inverses of $A$ and $B$ while ensuring that the result always has nonnegative entries.

Comment: that is what I am looking for. Thank you!